# Secondary Monitor Turning Itself on Shortly After Sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep, power-management

I've been Googling for a solution for quite some time now and most of everything I can find only relates to *waking* the computer.

In my case, the my laptop (ThinkPad P1 Gen 2) turns off displays, the secondary monitor sees 'No Signal' and turns off. When the computer fully enters sleep mode, a short while later, the secondary monitor flashes 'No Signal' before the screen turns black. The difference is now, the monitor is technically on (the power light shows blue instead of the red for standby). The monitor proceeds to flash 'No Signal' every 30 seconds or so.

The secondary monitor is an AOC 2752H (27"). I had a previous laptop that had no issues. I've tried updating drivers, reinstalling drivers, changing ports, and changing HDMI cables. Also I disabled Wake Tasks in power management. Nothing seems to solve the issue.

I would prefer to not have to pull the HDMI cable when I want the system to go to sleep, so hopefully that's not the only solution.

Any help is always much appreciated. I'm thinking the laptop may just be outputting some small level of voltage when it is asleep, causing the monitor not to turn off.

Comment: If you have the option to use a VGA connection that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops, as you say, stay splitting current. The laptops are "not designed" to support 2 monitors. A solution is updating your power drivers. Lenovo has a lot of power management drivers. Search yours and install them.

Another solution is unplugging your laptop from the wall while is sleeping.

---

If no method works, try this:

- Go to *control panel* and then select the power management options.
- Click on *change plan config* on any of the profiles.

Once inside you will notice that there are two items : '*turn off screen time*' and '*enter suspension mode*'. You need to select the **same time** for both (With battery or AC, depending on you).

---

If this one doesn't work too:

- Go to advanced options
- Change *Turn off hard drive* to the same time as you set the suspension mode before.
- Go to the *suspend* options and turn on *hybrid suspension*
- If it stills doesn't working, go to the *on-off button and top* functions and select *suspend* at the *close top action*

I hope it works. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your educated and informed response. Unfortunately after trying each of these options, the monitor still turns back on after the computer enters sleep mode. What's odd is the monitor turns off properly when the displays turn off, but when sleep happens, it gets some voltage from somewhere.

Comment: I don't know what happens tho. Try updating graphics drivers or going through the screen options. It's all I can do. Sorry.

Comment: I did look into the Event Viewer and found this error popping up around the time that the system would be trying to go to sleep "The User Energy Server Service queencreek service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Answer (score 0):

So I spent some time fiddling with various things all to no avail. Found out that it even keeps the monitor on when the computer itself is off. Ended up finding a 3rd HDMI cable and tried it. Works perfectly. So apparently the first two HDMI cables I tried just don't agree with my monitor/laptop setup.